# trying to retrieve specific Customer from Customers table

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm building a project with angular and php.  I'm trying to get a specific 'Customer' from Customers table and show his details on page but its not working. the error I get from console - angular.js:13550Error: [$parse:lexerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unexpected%20nextharacter%20&p1=s%200-0%20%5B%23%5D&p2=%23%2FcustomerCardDetails%2FcustomerDetails.customer_id

this is my code:

Customer.php

```
<?php
class Customer {

  private $table_name = "customers";

  public $customer_id;
  public $kind_Of_Customer;
  public $full_name;
  public $id;
  public $city;
  public $address;
  public $phone;
  public $phone_2;
  public $email;
  public $fax;
  public $referrer;
  public $comments;


}

?>
```

readCustomer.php

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

    include_once 'Customer.php';
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','hamatkin');

    mysqli_query($con,"SET character_set_client = utf8");
    mysqli_query($con,"SET character_set_connection = utf8");
    mysqli_query($con,"SET character_set_results = utf8");


    $customer = new Customer();


    $query = "SELECT customer_id, kind_Of_Customer, full_name, id, city, address,phone,phone_2 FROM customers where customer_id= 82";
    $result = $con->query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    // reset the result resource
    mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
    if( $result->num_rows==1)
    {


        $customer->kind_Of_Customer = $row['kind_Of_Customer'];
        $customer->full_name =$row['full_name'];
        $customer->id = $row['id'];
        $customer->city = $row['city'];
        $customer->address = $row['address'];
        $customer->phone = $row['phone'];
        $customer->phone_2 = $row['phone_2'];

    }
    $res = json_encode($customer);
     echo json_encode($res);

?>
```

customerCardDetailsCtrl.js - controller

```
"use strict";
angular.module('dataSystem').
controller('customerCardDetailsCtrl', function($scope, $http ,$routeParams, $location) {

  var customer_id = $routeParams.customer_id;
  $scope.customer_id = customer_id;
  var data = $.param({
    customer_id: customer_id
});

var config = {
    headers : {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
    }
}


  $http.post('api/readCustomer.php',data,config ).

  success(function(data){
    $scope.customerDetails = data;
    console.log($scope.customerDetails);
  }).
  error (function (error) {
    colsole.log(error);
  });
});
```

app.js - specific route

```
 .when('/customerCardDetails/:customer_id', {
                controller: "customerCardDetailsCtrl",
                templateUrl: '../hamatkin/Views/customerCardDetails.html',
                screenTitle: "",
                costumerHidden: false,
                reportsHidden: true,
                stockHidden: true,
                isIncome_expensesHidden: true,
                isNavTabHidden: false,
                isFooterHidden: false,
                ordersHidden: true
```

Comment: you should delete `mysql_data_seek($result, 0);`  It's has no effect in your code because it's part of the `mysql_` package (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php) and you're using `MySQLi` to connect to the DB.

Comment: @Beetlejuice thanks ive deleted it, not I have no errors but still doesn't work...

Comment: Any particular reason for running json_encode twice?

Comment: @Oli i changed it to   $res = json_encode($customer);
     echo $res;     stil the same problem

Comment: Given that the post and json response are correct, if you look at the angular error, it's complaining about the `#` character. Are you using it somewhere, either in the view, controller or perhaps in some routes?

Comment: @oli i fixed the angular error, and the console showing me the information of of a specific customer. the problem was instead of "MYSQL" i needed to write "MYSLI". now i want to show information on the web page. any idea how do i do it?